# How to make out of input field a hyperlink?

Tags: sapui5

As the title states, I would like to make out of an input a clickable hyperlink.

**Code:**

```xml
<Label text="Stackoverflow" />                              
<Input enabled="true" editable="false" name="Stackoverflow" value="Example" />
```

[image: Input with a Link]

**Issue:** I want to display `Example` in the input as value, however, when clicking on the `Example` - to take you to `stackoverflow.com`.

**Question:** How to make it possible?

Comment: Why you're using an input as a link? Why no Button or Link?

Comment: @alexP, due to design there are already 3x label input within the page, and the next which you see above is also suppose to have this structure, those, i wanted to know how to make the input as a hyperlink

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what the use of the links are, generally, `sap.m.InputBase` controls can contain links within the value state message (Since  1.78).

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], Fragment => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<Input xmlns="sap.m"
    width="12rem"
    valueState="Information"
    placeholder="Input with links"
    class="sapUiTinyMargin">
    <formattedValueStateText>
      <FormattedText htmlText="See %%0 and %%1.">
        <controls>
          <Link text="Link 1" press="alert('Link 1 clicked!')" />
          <Link text="Link 2" press="alert('Link 2 clicked!')" />
        </controls>
      </FormattedText>
    </formattedValueStateText>
  </Input>`,
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even if a link or button would be the better solution, here is my suggestion:

XML with custom attribute "url"

```
<Input enabled="true" editable="false" id="idInputStack" name="Stackoverflow" value="Example">
   <customData>
    <core:CustomData key="url" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com" writeToDom="true" />
  </customData>
</Input>
```

Controller:

```
var oInput = this.getView().byId("idInputStack");
oInput.addEventDelegate({
    onclick: function() {
        document.location.href = oInput.data("url"); //get custom attribute url
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First we would provide an id to the Input control so that we could refer to the same from the controller.

```html
<Input enabled="true" editable="false" name="Stackoverflow" value="Example" id="myInputLinkId"/>
```

2. Now we could add the typical user click event to the Input field by attaching a Browser event to the same and place it in the onInit() hook method so that it is always accessible.

```js
onInit: function () {
            this.getView().byId("myInputLinkId").attachBrowserEvent('click',function(){ window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");});
        }
```